# Capture values from a string based on pattern

Tags: javascript, python, regex, go

I am looking for an approach to the following problem. It captures all `*` values from the string using a provided pattern.

```
function capture(pattern, string) {
}
```

Example:

Input

- Pattern `The quick brown * jumps over the lazy *`
- String `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

Output `[fox, dog]`

Is it possible to solve it using regex?

Comment: Show what you tried so far.

Comment: Will pattern word length and string word length always be same?

Comment: @CeriseLimón I have tried it. I will post it. I know I can do it multiple iteration but got stuck trying to achieve it in a single iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to convert the pattern into a regular expression that captures the expected values from the given string:

```
func capture(pat, str string) []string {
    // Capture all sequences of non-whitespace characters between word boundaries.
    re := strings.Replace(pat, "*", `(\b\S+\b)`, -1)
    groups := regexp.MustCompile(re).FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1)
    if groups == nil {
        return []string{}
    }
    return groups[0][1:]
}

func main() {
    pat := "The quick brown * jumps over the lazy *"
    str := "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

    fmt.Printf("OK: %s\n", capture(pat, str))
    // OK: [fox dog]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
pat = "The quick brown * jumps over the lazy *"

result = []
for p, s in zip(pat.split(), str.split()):
    if p == "*":
        result.append(s)

print(result)
```